# AngularJS ui-router save previous state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to save the current state, I don't mean saving url and params, I want to save the entire view with scopes.. In fact, I want to implement a facebook like search system, but differently. I want to display the results on the entire page, so I'll replace the current main State, and when the search bar will be cleared, then we will restore the previous state. I don't want to rebuild the state to restore the state instantly (no server requests) + to avoid complicated operations (eg. infinite scroll data..). I've found ui'router extras (sticky state) plugin, but we need to define what state to save with states definitions..
I apologize for my bad english..

Answer (score 0):

You can save the date in the local storage using [angular local storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage). It will save you a trip to the server for data.

Answer (score 0):

This is an architectural decision. The answer to this question will not be short and can be very subjective and different people will have different ways to implementing it.

What I would suggest is that you leverage local storage and do all actions on data present in local storage.

The way you would do this is to first understand that all server requests need to be done through A service that return what's present in localstorage is network is offline.

So all AJAX calls will be done from the controller like this

```js
var getMeRequest = AuthService.getMe();
getMeRequest.promise.then(function(response){ 
  if(response.cached) {
    // $update views if need be  
  } else {
    //Some code
  }
});
```

And in the AuthService file, you'd do it like this:

```js
// In AuthService

this.getMe() =  function () {
  if(network.online) {
    //Make AJAX call
    // Update localstorage with whatever response
    return {response: locastorageData, cached:false};
  } else {
    return {response: localstorageData, cached:true};
  }
  
};
```

This will not only let you make all the ajax calls as if you were online, but also allow the controller to update the view based on whether the response is cached or not.